# find OpenGL sound process library

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm working on raytracing algorithm and I want to make changes on sound file 
Can you help me to find any (lib or class for OpenGL c++) for sound process to wave file "or any other types(mp3 ...)"

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is for Graphics rendering. It can be used for certain types of generic processing, but sound processing is done on the CPU due to various reasons, including floating point capabilities required.

For sound processing, you can use Audacity (http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)